# How do I get Google to index my page with history.pushState?

Tags: javascript, web

I'm building a page with history.pushState. Can Google index my page with history.pushState? How should I do for Google to index?

Answer (score 0):

If you want google to index your site, look into the Google Search Console (https://search.google.com/search-console/about). Google Search Console, once you verify that you own a site, will index it and also provide recommendations for how to improve your search result rating.

`history.pushState()` has nothing to do with your search result rating. It just adds an entry into a user's browsing history. (Press CTRL+H on Chrome to view browsing history)